# Encode Json and get a value from it in laravel

Tags: laravel

json:

```
[
   {"student":"a","relation":"son","id":"74"},
   {"student":"b","relation":"son","id":"75"}
]
```

I want to get the value of each id in this json.(ie 74 and 75)
This json is from a column called relation from user table.

I am working with laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert JSON to an array and [`collect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-collect) to convert it to a collection. Then use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) to get all IDs.

```
$ids = collect(json_decode($json, true))->pluck('id');
```

Or use [`array_pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-pluck):

```
$ids = array_pluck(json_decode($json, true), 'id');
```

If you want to get IDs from the query, use [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) instead of `get()`:

```
$users = User::where('role', 'parent')->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. But how wil i get the id of that row? $userss = User::where('role','parent')->select('relation')->get();  $array = json_decode($userss, true);$ids = collect($array)->pluck('id');

Comment: $userss = User::where('role','parent')->select('relation')->get(); This will just select the relation column and i have 10 columns and as you said i wil get the ids from json. after getting the json ids i am comapring them against another value and if it is equal i want the id of that particular row whose json this was.

Comment: @MohammadSheraz I'm sorry I don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can save the need to JSON decode that column by adding `protected $casts = ['column'  => 'array'];`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Let me explain you again. I hav 10 rows.Each row might have a value for relation column that is the above mentioned json. i need the ids from that json and i need to comapre them against a value(any value). if there is a match then i want the id of the row from which this json was obtained

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I got it. Thanks a Lot !!